# Reaching a data in json using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, twitter

I want to get the username's profile image. So i prefer to use twitter api version 1 for this.(The regular version of api is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show)). But my code doesn't return any data. How can i fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {   
var userPage = "https//twitter.com/jack"; 
var arr = userPage.split("/");
var username = "";

for(i=3;i<4;i++)
username += arr[i];

var page = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='+username;

        $.getJSON(page, function(data) {
            alert(data.profile_image_url);
        });

})

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do `console.log(data)` and inspect the object.

Comment: There is certainly something wrong with your `page`, `data.profile_image_url` _will_ extract the image-url (at least for the examplecode). Guess `username` is wrong.

Comment: Do you get any data back, or do you have an error? You might be getting an error for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Than if XHR is successful, do what @xbonez suggest to see what data you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"&callback=?"` to the URL to force jsonp format to get around the Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue.

```
var page = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='+username + "&callback=?";
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XCzF4/)**

**[JSONP](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)**:

> The way JSONP works is simple, but requires a little bit of
>   server-side cooperation. Basically, the idea is that you let the
>   client decide on a small chunk of arbitrary text to prepend to the
>   JSON document, and you wrap it in parentheses to create a valid
>   JavaScript document (and possibly a valid function call).
>
> The client decides on the arbitrary prepended text by using a query
>   argument named jsonp with the text to prepend. Simple! With an empty
>   jsonp argument, the result document is simply JSON wrapped in
>   parentheses.